# trouble invoking static method using reflection and c#

Tags: c#, reflection

i have this two classes:

```
Item<T> : BusinessBase<T> where T : Item<T>
{
     public static T NewItem()
     {
      //some code here
     }
}
Video : Item <Video>
{

}
```

now i want to invoke **NewItem()** method on class Video using reflection.
when i try with this:

```
MethodInfo inf = typeof(Video).GetMethod("NewItem", BindingFlags.Static);
```

the object **inf** after executing this line still is null.
can i invoke static **NewItem()** method on class Video?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to specifiy [BindingFlags.**Public**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) and [BindingFlags.**FlattenHierarchy**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) in addition to [BindingFlags.**Static**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx):

```
MethodInfo inf = typeof(Video).GetMethod("NewItem",
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
```

Alternatively, you can get the method from the declaring type without [BindingFlags.**FlattenHierarchy**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx):

```
MethodInfo inf = typeof(Item<Video>).GetMethod("NewItem",
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

I've tried both ways and they both work.